# Conditional exclusion of file from compilation in maven project

Tags: java, file, maven, compilation

What the easiest/right way to conditionally exclude a java file from compilation in a maven project?

I would like to be able to set a 'boolean' properties in the pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <IncludeMayBe>true</IncludeMayBe>
</properties>

...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            ????

        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is there a way to fiddle something with the compiler plugin? Or should I go for profiles? I feel like creating a profile is overkill, but may be this is the only solution...

**EDIT:**

We have established that profiles are the solution. For conditional activation from within the pom.xml, one can use the following:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <IncludeMayBe>true</IncludeMayBe>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: What is the root problem you're trying to solve with this exclusion? I'm feeling there might be a more intuitive solution than optionally excluding a source file.

Comment: For example, in a large project, you may want to develop side code to check the behavior of your application and be able to collect data while running in test environment. But in production, you don't want or need that code. Removing it creates smaller more optimized jars.

Comment: You are looking for profiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use the [Build helper maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/).
Using this, you can have several source directories.
Then you can control what source directories are included using profiles.

Assuming you have your monitoring classes under src/monitoring/java you could add the following to the  element in your pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>monitoring</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>${basedir}/src/monitoring/java</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I have taken a look at this plugin, but it does not seem to enable 'conditional' inclusion/exclusion of code. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to control it with maven profiles. For the use case with a jar with extra monitoring for testing, I'd have a profile named "monitoring" containing build helper plugin adding the extra source folder, then you build it with "mvn clean install -Pmonitoring" or just "mvn clean install" for the build without extra classes.

Comment: Ok, then, profiles it will be. At least, this issue is clarified.

Comment: Ok, this answer was written 8 years ago, but now I'm wondering if it can be used to add additional Kotlin-sources and not only Java-sources.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using the compiler plugin (see below).

But even if you could, it doesn't feel right.  It would mean that the files in a artifact JAR file would depend on command line switches and/or environmental settings, and that makes it harder for other folks to reproduce builds.

My gut feeling is that you'd be better of modularizing your maven project and using profiles to determine what modules get built.

---

I had a look at the source code of the compiler plugin mojo, and it looks like there's no way to configure source include / exclude filters.  At some point, someone has implemented filters, but the relevant `Map` objects are private and there is no way to populate them, and hence no way to use this functionality.

The code is here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/

I guess you could hack your own version of the plugin ... but it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: This is not an issue in our case (i.e., reproducing builds). We are happy with it.