# Is there a way to prevent IntelliJ IDEA from compiling logback.groovy?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, logback

I have a groovy project in IntelliJ IDEA that uses `logback.groovy`. It's in `src/main/resources` so that it ends up in the classpath of the project, but IDEA compiles it into `logback.class`. Logback expects this to be in `.groovy` format, so this won't do. Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I just want `logback.groovy` in my classpath for running unit tests and webapp debugging.

Comment: If you are using GMaven plugin instead of basic Ant, you can follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6032601/2051952).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not using either of those :-). I'm using gradle, but that's outside the scope of this problem since everything works when building with gradle. Basically I want the contents of `src/main/resources` in the classpath just directly copied, not compiled in any way.

Comment: If everything works when building with gradle, then IntelliJ should be using `build.gradle` to do the same process during compiling, right? Am I missing anything?

Comment: More of a workaround, could you use the `maven-resources-plugin` to copy the groovy file from say `src/main/groovy`, thereby skipping compilation?

Comment: @dmahapatro: intellij uses its own builder to compile the project. JetGradle (built-in to IDEA) builds `.iml` files from `build.gradle`. In this question I'm not too concerned about that file being generated, but more on how to do this with *just* IDEA.

Comment: @vikingsteve sorry if it wasn't clear, I'm not using maven, but just vanilla IDEA. I know gradle (and I assume maven) handles this file correctly, but for some reason my IDE does not.

Comment: @Joe ok thanks for clarifying that, I presumed it was maven from the source path you gave.

Answer (score 3):

IDEA 13 now supports new types of directory assignments under your content root: the relevant one for this question is "resources".
In previous versions, IDEA only supported marking directories as "sources" or "tests".

So the new correct answer is to mark **src/main/resources** directory as a resources folder of your content root.  By marking the contents of a directory as "resources", you're telling IDEA that the contents are not source code but need to be accessible on the classpath at runtime.

[Added as a separate answer because the first one is still potentially useful if your file is stuck under your source tree for whatever reason - feel free to merge it in to the other answer if that's more appropriate.]

Answer (score 2):

I guess /src/main/resources is marked in IDEA as a source root?  That's pretty much explicitly telling IDEA "the stuff under this directory is source files".

You could try adding the file to /Settings/Project Settings/Compiler/Excludes - but that will probably mean that your file won't get copied onto your output path (and thus won't be on the runtime classpath so logback won't see it).

My personal solution is that my logback.groovy sits outside of my /src tree - I consider it to be configuration rather than a source/resource file.  My config directory itself is then added to the runtime classpath directly via /Project Structure/Modules//Dependencies (marked as runtime scope).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to modify the artifact to explicitly include `logback.groovy` in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory. It isn't ideal since this file could only be referenced by the absolute path and not as a project file, so any suggestions are still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I put logback.groovy in src/main/resources and added it to Resources patterns in IDEA's Compiler settings (ctrl + alt + s; Compiler > Resource patterns). And it works :)